# Deciding the lifetime of dependencies in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

I have been looking into the following code(I know it is ADAL and not MSAL, but was interested in the DI).

https://github.com/juunas11/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-sample-aspnetcore/blob/master/ApiOnBehalfSample/Startup.cs

The dependencies are registered as Singleton. Is that right?
Is there an issue in them being registered as Scoped?

What is the correct way of deciding the lifetime of the dependencies?

**Update:**

In the above code uses ADAL to authorize the user and get the user profile using Graph API.

There are 3 dependencies registered in the Startup.cs class,

```
services.AddSingleton<IGraphApiService, GraphApiService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationProvider, OnBehalfOfMsGraphAuthenticationProvider>();
```

So I understand the httpcontextaccessor should be a singleton.
The IAuthenticationProvider (which is used to create Graph Client), should that be singleton?
Also can the IGraphAPIService which calls the Graph API endpoint and returns user profile info be scoped?

Comment: This question is completely dependent on an external resource, which makes it unsuitable for Stack Overvlow. You might want to rephrase the question or at least post the relevant parts of the code in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Hey here's a quick overview about Dependency Injection [Service Lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes) on .NET from Microsoft official article. Hope it helps you to decide.

**Transient**
Transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested from the service container. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services. Register transient services with AddTransient.

In apps that process requests, transient services are disposed at the end of the request.

**Scoped**
For web applications, a scoped lifetime indicates that services are created once per client request (connection). Register scoped services with AddScoped.

In apps that process requests, scoped services are disposed at the end of the request.

When using Entity Framework Core, the AddDbContext extension method registers DbContext types with a scoped lifetime by default.

**Singleton**
Singleton lifetime services are created either:

The first time they're requested.
By the developer, when providing an implementation instance directly to the container. This approach is rarely needed.
Every subsequent request of the service implementation from the dependency injection container uses the same instance. If the app requires singleton behavior, allow the service container to manage the service's lifetime. Don't implement the singleton design pattern and provide code to dispose of the singleton. Services should never be disposed by code that resolved the service from the container. If a type or factory is registered as a singleton, the container disposes the singleton automatically.

Register singleton services with AddSingleton. Singleton services must be thread safe and are often used in stateless services.

In apps that process requests, singleton services are disposed when the ServiceProvider is disposed on application shutdown. Because memory is not released until the app is shut down, consider memory use with a singleton service.