# How can I know what kind of service to setup?

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-6.0

I am currently developping a web API, together with the related website. I was about to add in my Startup.cs my new service :

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

But since then, I am wondering how can we know what "type" of service should we add ? There is a bunch of possibilities :

```
AddScoped
AddSingleton
AddTransient
AddSession
...
```

And I think this is possibly confusing. So how can we know what type of service makes the most sense for what we want to add (repositories, services, ...) ? What aspects should we take into consideration ?

Also, what impact does it have on our applications ? Does it change anything regarding security, performance or anything else ?

Thanks.

EDIT : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/addtransient-addscoped-and-addsingleton-services-differences) is a better question/explanation

Comment: Yes. Different lifetimes introduce different behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643677/deciding-the-lifetime-of-dependencies-in-net-core/70653518 Singleton will ensure there can only be a single instance, so would be bad for a stateless API. Scoped is most commonly used since it gives you a new instance per request.

Comment: Just FYI `AddSession` is not a lifetime, it's a call which adds [session state support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to your ASP.NET Core app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `AddSession` is not a lifetime, it's a call which adds [session state support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to your ASP.NET Core app.

As for scope types - you should read the documentation carefully:

1. [Dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)
2. [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Both articles have quite a lot in common and describe the support of the [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI) software design pattern (which is a technique for achieving [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (IoC) between classes and their dependencies) which is build into the framework.

[This particular section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes) covers the service lifetimes:

> **Transient**
> Transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested from the service container. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services. Register transient services with `AddTransient`.
> In apps that process requests, transient services are disposed at the end of the request.

> **Scoped**
> For web applications, a scoped lifetime indicates that services are created once per client request (connection). Register scoped services with `AddScoped`.
> In apps that process requests, scoped services are disposed at the end of the request.
> When using Entity Framework Core, the `AddDbContext` extension method registers `DbContext` types with a scoped lifetime by default.
> By default, in the development environment, resolving a service from another service with a longer lifetime throws an exception. For more information, see [Scope validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scope-validation).

> **Singleton**
> Singleton lifetime services are created either:
>
> - The first time they're requested.
> - By the developer, when providing an implementation instance directly to the container. This approach is rarely needed.
>
> Every subsequent request of the service implementation from the dependency injection container uses the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0). It depends on whats the behaviour of your program. The different types describes the lifetime of the services.

`Singleton` There only will be one instance

`Scoped` There only will be one instance for the current request

`Transient` Everytime the instance is used it will be newly generated

If you want to use the same instance during the whole process you can use a singleton (e.g. for session handling). A scoped instance makes sense for things that are necessary during the request proccess.